Regular Expression to match Quoted or Unquoted windows file paths
I have text that I need to extract all file or folder paths (bold text below).
Unquoted paths have no spaces and need to be matched as well as quoted paths.
This is DOT.NET regex flavor in C#.
"C:\Future\Code In Progress" arbitrary unmatched text C:\Data\Code v:\Bless\Test.txt "D:\APPZ\Bam Bam\Malkop.mp3"
The regex below matches the quoted paths without issue so now I need to match the unquoted paths. Also the regex for the unquoted paths need to ensure the path isn't preceded by a quote to eliminate match redundancies.
Regex.Matches (input, @"\""[a-zA-Z]:\\.*?\""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

The regex: @""[a-zA-Z]:\.*?"" isn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Read the regex specification  and figure out a solution - just some hints [^ and {0,1} and grouping with ( and ) - and your regex does not work if there is a digit in the folder or files names, or e. g. an underscore or even unicode characters for non-english languages or smileys..., all allowed in Windows files system paths! And you even forgot the space inside the path! Only absolute paths?

This can take you very close [a-zA-Z]:\(.?)(?=([" ][a-zA-Z]:\)|(")) if you will add " or c:\ to the end of the text it fully works. it extract all paths in one step. hope it will work for you. keep notice that in the case of unmatched text after path without " you will need addition to discover those cases.

I ended up using two regex strings.
string quoted = @"(?<=\"")[a-zA-Z]:\\.*?(?=\"")";
string unquoted = @"(?<!\"")[a-zA-Z]:\\[^\s]*";


Use Regex in C#:
\"\w+\:(\\\w+[ \w+]*)+(\.\w+)?\"

So, your code should be:
Regex.Matches (input, @"\""\w+\:(\\\w+[ \w+]*)+(\.\w+)?\""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)


You may validate here: regexstorm.net
Regex Explanation:

